# SUMIF YYYY-MM-DD = TODAY?

Tags: excel, date, formula

I have fields that look like, and has to look like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD G/G
YYYY-MM-DD U/G
YYYY-MM-DD G/U
YYYY-MM-DD U/U
```

I want to show in a cell, the SUM of the dates that correspond to the date today is. Is this possible, and how? Like:

Done today: XX

Comment: This question is in no way understandable please read this link before posting a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agreed. It's really not that clear what you're asking. Is that string in a SINGLE cell, for example? Is the format of the entry always consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess, assuming:

1. You have a column of dates and a separate column of other data.
2. The dates are in ColumnA.
3. Since your example shows a single result, the other data is irrelevant for current purposes.
4. Dates are date/time indices, not text strings.
5. You don't want to **sum** dates (*adding* the day war broke out to the date you were born is nonsensical) but **count** them.

Then perhaps:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,TODAY())
```

which, depending upon locale, may need to be:

```
  =COUNTIF(A:A;TODAY())
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  Sorry I was unclear. Yes, it's a column and seperate cells, and I want to count the number of cells that have TODAY as date. I've checked now and yes, they are formated as dates. Still get an error though, and I've also tried to remove G/G etc from the field to be a 100%. To be extra clear, I want AH12 to AH13 counted, so have written: "=COUNTIF(AH12:AH13,TODAY())" (without the quotes). AH12 has the value "2015-03-13", and AH13 has the value "2015-03-13". Any suggestions?

Comment: This worked "=COUNTIF(AH12:AH13;TODAY())". It only worked without the text after the date though. Can an exception be made somehow, or do I need to add a column next to it for that?The error was "The formula you typed contains an error. For information about fixing common formula problems, click Help. To get assistance in entering a function, click Functions Wizard (Formulas tab, Function Library group). If you are not truing to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quotation mark (')."